# Error When Creating Chloropleth Map Using Python Folium

Tags: python, typeerror, folium, choropleth

So I'm using this site to help me create a chloropleth map on python: https://stjohn.github.io/teaching/seminar4/s17/cw6.html and the first step/block of code won't run for me. This is my code:

```
import folium
nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.75, -74.125])

nycMap.choropleth(geo_path="nycmap.geojson.json",
                     fill_opacity=0.5, line_opacity=0.5
                     ) 

nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
```

This is the error I get:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/folium/folium.py", line 411
    warnings.warn(
FutureWarning: The choropleth  method has been deprecated. Instead use the new Choropleth class, which has the same arguments. See the example notebook 'GeoJSON_and_choropleth' for how to do this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI233/PRAC.py", line 7, in <module>
    nycMap.choropleth(geo_path="nycmap.geojson.json",
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/folium/folium.py", line 418, in choropleth
    self.add_child(Choropleth(*args, **kwargs))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'geo_data'
```

I did edit the original code from the website to match the files I want to use, but I also did leave some things the same because I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to put for it. Like in the second line of code, I'm not sure what I should put for location and also in the last line of code, I put 'index.html' because I do have an html file where I eventually plan to upload this map to launch it on a site, but I'm not sure if that's what I needed to do there.

This is the json file I'm using for the map: https://data-beta-nyc-files.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/35dd04fb-81b3-479b-a074-a27a37888ce7/d085e2f8d0b54d4590b1e7d1f35594c1pediacitiesnycneighborhoods.geojson?Signature=GXt98kpRQsJP5kH06TqnZtxvptU%3D&Expires=1605154652&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAWM5UKMRH2KITC3QA

And this is the information I want to input into the map: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYC-crime/qb7u-rbmr

Answer (score 0):

The warning tells *The **choropleth**  method has been deprecated. Instead use the new **Choropleth** class, which has the same arguments.* e.g use **folium.Choropleth**( *initialized with Capital letter* ) class, which also requires the **geo_data** argument which is the first in the order of arguments, instead of **Map.choropleth** such as

```
import folium

url = 'https://stjohn.github.io/teaching/seminar4/s17'
nyc_geo = f'{url}/schoolDistricts.json'
nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.75, -74.125], zoom_start=5.5)

folium.Choropleth(geo_data=nyc_geo,
                  fill_opacity=0.5,
                  line_opacity=0.5
                  ) 

nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your code(sorry, I'm not exactly a coding wiz). So you're extracting the map directly form the website? How can I do that with a GeoJSON file from my computer? I tried deleting the url variable and just starting with `nyc_geo = 'filename'` but I received another error. Also, how about the data that I want to put on the map?

Comment: No error should raise @user13451867 . Nevertheless, alternatively, you can try replacing `nyc_geo` such as `nyc_geo = 'C:\\Python\\App\\folium\\schoolDistricts.json'` to a path in your filesystem after downloading the json at that path. Then you'll see the file `index.html` there.